# difference between dsp.fft and fft

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to apply an FFT for a matrix

```
A = [5 7 8; 0 1 9; 4 3 6];
A(:,:,2) = [1 0 4; 3 5 6; 9 8 7];
```

When I use `fft2(A)` I have a result. When I use `hFFT = dsp.FFT; x = step(hFFT,A);`, the results are differnt. Why?

Comment: What language/library are you asking about? MATLAB?

Comment: Assuming this is MATLAB, the result are different because `fft2` is a two-dimensioanl DFT while `fft`/`dsp.FFT` is a one-dimensional DFT. Those are different operations and aren't immediately interchangeable.